# JDBC not working properly within Java program

Tags: java, sql, oracle, jdbc

This is something I do not understand. I have a pre-made SQL structure that I load into a local JDBC database. I can add elements to tables and work with said elements with this program. However, when I try to add elements that already exist on the pre-made SQL table, it locks up like shown below:

[image]

This does not happen when we are trying to add an element that we created in the Java program as shown below:

[image]

I can not figure out what is happening, has anyone had this bug before? Or does anyone know how to fix it?  For some reason I can not get this to work. I have researched and worked on this for the last two weeks and the bug will not go away. I am pasting my code below.

Driver.java:

```
package dylanstepp;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.sql.*;

public class Driver {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"); //Load the Oracle JDBC driver
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("Could not load the driver");
    }
    try {
        try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
            int choice;
            boolean loopTrigger = true;


            try (Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","Chicken1") //connect oracle
            ) { 
                Statement st = conn.createStatement();
                PreparedStatement updateGrade = conn.prepareStatement("Update Registered "
                        + "SET grade = ? Where ssn = ?");

                //st.executeUpdate("insert into login values('user2','123456')");
                do {
                    //User Interface Text
                    System.out.println("*********************************************************************"
                            + "\n***                                                               ***"
                            + "\n***             Welcome to Online Registration System             ***"
                            + "\n***                                                               ***"
                            + "\n*********************************************************************"
                            + "\n\n\t1. Add a course\n\t2. Delete a course\n\t3. Add a student\n\t4. Delete a student"
                            + "\n\t5. Register a course\n\t6. Drop a course\n\t7. Check student registration"
                            + "\n\t8. Upload Grades\n\t9. Check grades\n\t10. Quit");

                    choice = sc.nextInt();

                    Course cOb = new Course();
                    Student sOb = new Student();
                    Registry rOb = new Registry();

                    switch (choice) {
                        case 1: //add a course
                            cOb.addCourse(st);
                            break;

                        case 2: //delete a course
                            cOb.delCourse(st);
                            break;

                        case 3: //add a student
                            sOb.addStudent(st);
                            break;

                        case 4: //delete a student
                            sOb.delStudent(st);
                            break;

                        case 5: //register a course
                            rOb.registerCourse(st);
                            break;

                        case 6: //drop a course
                            rOb.dropCourse(st);
                            break;

                        case 7: //check student registration
                            rOb.checkGrade(st);
                            break;

                        case 8: //upload grades
                            rOb.uploadGrades(updateGrade, st);
                            break;

                        case 9: //check grades
                            rOb.checkGrade(st);
                            break;

                        case 10://quitting the application
                            System.out.println("Quitting Application...");
                            loopTrigger = false;
                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid option, please select again.");
                            break;
                    }
                } while (loopTrigger);
                updateGrade.close();
                st.close();
                sc.close();
                conn.close();
            }
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("Sorry, there was an error!");
        System.err.println(e.getMessage());
    }

}
}
```

This is happening with every one of these functions, so I will add just the Course.java class below.

Course.java:

```
package dylanstepp;

import java.util.*;
import java.sql.*;

public class Course {

private final Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

public void addCourse(Statement st){   //**********This function adds a course to the database.
    String courseCode, courseTitle;
    int entriesChanged;   


    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a course code you would like to add: ");
        courseCode = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from Course where code = '" + courseCode + "'");

        if (rs.next()) {
            System.out.println("This course code already exists, please try again.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter the title for the course: ");
            courseTitle = sc.nextLine().toUpperCase();
            entriesChanged = st.executeUpdate("Insert into Course values ('" + courseCode + "','" + courseTitle + "')");
            System.out.println("You just added " + entriesChanged + " entries to the course list.");
        }
        rs.close();  //**********Closed the result set in this function.
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error during runtime, Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }

}

public void delCourse(Statement st) {     //**********This function deletes a course from the database.
    String courseCode;
    int entriesChangedCourse, entriesChangedReg;
    try {
        System.out.println("Please enter a course code you would like to delete: ");
        courseCode = sc.next().toUpperCase();
        ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("Select * From Course Where code = " + courseCode);
        if (rs.next()) {
            entriesChangedReg = st.executeUpdate("Delete from Registered Where code = " + courseCode);
            entriesChangedCourse = st.executeUpdate("Delete From Course Where code = " + courseCode);
            System.out.println("You just deleted " + (entriesChangedCourse + entriesChangedReg) + " entries from the database.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Could not find course code, please try again.");
        }
        rs.close();  //**********Closed the result set in this function.
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        System.out.println("There was an error during runtime, Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
}

public void ScannerClose()
{
    sc.close();
}
}
```

Anything in this schema that is premade and input throught the SQL console is what causes the program to stop functioning when trying to add a value that already exists in the Java program.

```
Drop table Registered;
Drop table Course;
Drop table Student;

Create table Student
(
ssn numeric primary key,
name char(50),
address varchar(100),
major    char(10)
);
Create table Course
(
code char(10) primary key,
title varchar(50)
);
 Create table Registered
(
ssn numeric,
code char(10),
year int,
semester char(10),
grade char(1),
foreign key (ssn) references Student(ssn),
foreign key (code) references Course(code),
    primary key (ssn,code,year,semester)
);

Insert into Student values(555550001,'Tom Hanks', '100 Ellen St., Spartanburg, SC 29301', 'CIS');
Insert into Student values(555550003,'Matt Cutts', '130 Martin St., Spartanburg, SC 29301', 'CS');
Insert into Student  values(555550007,'Mary Jane', '5340 University Way, Spartanburg, SC 29303', 'CS');
Insert into Student  values(555550005,'Courtney Ranes', '1670 Woodwill St., Spartanburg, SC 29301', 'Math');
Insert into Student  values(555550002,'Terry Love', '346 Hill St., Spartanburg, SC 29301', 'CIS');
Insert into Student  values(555550006,'Steve Harry', '7543 Briarwood St., Spartanburg, SC 29304', 'CIS');
Insert into Student  values(555550004,'Will Smith', '7342 Esquire Dr., Spartanburg, SC 29301', 'Math');
Insert into Student  values(555550008,'Caroline Manzo', '246 Altanta Hwy, Spartanburg, SC 29302', 'CS');
Insert into Student  values(555550009,'Jerry Hood', '752 Ellen St., Spartanburg, SC 29301', 'HIS');
Insert into Student  values(555550011,'Underson Hoper', '768 Hood St., Spartanburg, SC 29302', 'CS');

Insert into Course  values('CS200', 'Computer Science I');
Insert into Course  values('CS300', 'Computer Science II');
Insert into Course  values('MATH200', 'Algebra');
Insert into Course  values('MATH100', 'Pre-Calculus');
Insert into Course  values('CS520', 'Database Systems');
Insert into Course  values('CS350', 'Analysis of Algorithms');

Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550001, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550002, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550003, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550004, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550005, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550006, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550007, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550008, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550009, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550011, 'MATH100',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550003, 'CS200',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550008, 'CS200',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550007, 'CS200',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550011, 'CS200',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550003, 'CS520',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550008, 'CS520',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550011, 'CS350',2013, 'Spring');
Insert into Registered(ssn,code,year,semester) values(555550003, 'CS350',2013, 'Spring');
```

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think you use two instances of ``Scanner`` on ``System.in``. Try sharing the instance instead of creating seperate ones.

Comment: I did that, however it had the same issue with bot telling the user that a name that was premade is in the table, instead it locks up like shown above

Comment: So wait, are you saying it freezes when you enter a course code that already exists in the database?

Comment: It stops responding if I enter a course code that already exists in the PREMADE sql table.  If I add a value I can make the program tell me that it exists if I try to add it again.  The newly added value do get added to the database I checked, for some reason it doesn't work with the premade values